# Coin problem with permutations

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, additive-combinatorics, semigroups-and-monoids

Let $a,b,c$ be positive integers with gcd$(a,b,c)=1$, and let $\mathbb{N}$ denote the set of nonnegative integers.

It is well known that $\mathbb{N} \setminus (a \mathbb{N}+b \mathbb{N} + c \mathbb{N})$ is a finite set, but it seems difficult to determine a formula for its maximum (the Frobenius number).  This is the famous 'coin problem'.

I am asking about a related problem.  Consider now the set of *vectors* $$(1,1,1) \mathbb{N} \setminus \sum (a,b,c) \mathbb{N},$$
where the sum ranges over all six permutations of $(a,b,c)$.  Is it necessarily the case that, for relatively prime $a,b,c$, there is a maximum constant integral vector in this set?  If so, what can we say about the maximum?

I suspet this may be connected (via a clever argument) with the ordinary postage stamp problem, but a quick 10-minute effort on my part failed.

**edit**: (here come the hypotheses!)  $a+b+c$ must be odd

If this answer turns out to be negative, or the question turns out to be hard, let's make it easier by increasing the number of coordinates: $(1,\dots,1) \mathbb{N} \setminus \sum \mathbf{v} \mathbb{N}$, where the sum is over all $\mathbf{v}$ with one entry of each of $a$, $b$, $c$, and the rest $0$.  Does this modification of the problem start to approach the ordinary coin problem for $a,b,c$?

Comment: Its infinite.  Use a geometric picture, and imagine a,a+1, a+2 as your tuple.

Comment: I made a mistake and replaced the line with the whole space N^3.   I believe the answer is yes because you can form enough distinct target vectors in your set.  I will see if I can provide a proof.

Comment: This is what I initially thought (enough target vectors), but actually I think you were right the first time.  I just tried $a = 1$, $b = 2$, $c = 3$ and noticed a parity argument rules out odd constant vectors.  There may be a hypothesis which makes the (first) problem interesting again.

Comment: Interesting. I think there is a proof when b+c is not a multiple of a.  Characterizing the tuples that "fill the line" would also be interesting.

Comment: I think something like a=b+c mod p for some prime p may lead to holes, and otherwise not.  In any case, I'm glad to have inspired some progress.

Comment: There is a sense in which the 'restricted' postage stamp problem plays a role here.  For, if we take $a+c=2b$, we have $(a,b,c)=(a,a,a)+(0,t,2t)$ and our number of summands must exhaust all possible congruence classes (mod $t$).

Comment: I might not understand the question, but how could you get an $(x,x,x)$ for which $a+b+c$ doesn't divide $3x$? I think because of this the only solution to your problem is $a=b=c=1$.

Answer (score 2):

I guess the answer should be that $(a,b,c)$ fills the line if and only if there is an integral combination of its permutations equaling $(1,1,1)$.  We want the elementary divisors of a certain $3 \times 6$ matrix.  Working out explicit conditions should be do-able.  I wonder if there is a slick argument.

There is also a neat connection with semi-magic squares, I think.

When allowing longer vectors which are permutations of $(a,b,c,0,\dots,0)$, it feels like their Frobenius number is the truth, but again with some extra necessary divisibility conditions.

(Sorry if my question was elementary.)

Comment: It seems to me that you get all but finitely many elements iff the subgroup generated by the intersection of your two monoids is the whole line. I am not sure you can generate a subgroup before intersecting. Anyway this is polynomial time decidable.

Comment: The sum of entries of any representable vector is divisible by $a+b+c$, so $a+b+c\mid 3$, which, under the condition $a,b,c>0$, means $a=b=c=1$.

Comment: I am embarrassed to have missed this!  So no nontrivial triple of positive integers fills the line by combinations of its permutations, correct?  Maybe the problem is interesting if we relax to $a,b,c \in \mathbb{Z}$.